# Points not showing on map on QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, layers, coordinates, csv

I uploaded my coordinates as a CSV file and they show on the blank page on QGIS but when I try to make them show on the map they don't, either if I use OpenStreetMap or Esri Satellite, it's like they don't exist, I don't even know if they are located somewhere else or if they just don't show up, I have no idea on how to fix this. A friend told me she used dnrgps to upload her coordinates on QGIS but they don't show on the right places from where she took them, but at least they showed. I know my coordinates are right, I used geo planner and they got pinpointed in the right location. So how should I do to map them on QGIS?

[image]

Comment: It sounds like your points are in a different coordinate reference system, can you give an example of your poins X, Y coordinates and what spatial reference you defined when you loaded them from CSV. Your view is in WGS84 Geographic (EPSG:4326), if your points CRS is undefined or wrong they will not appear on your canvas.

Answer (score 10):

Look at the layer's order, it is because OpenStreetMap layer is covering everything. Just drag down the OpenStreetMap  to the bottom of the layer list. It should fix your problem.

[image]